# Date overflow in PHP

Tags: php

I happily use this expression on my PHP 5.4 server

```
date('d.m.Y', strtotime('+100 years'));
```

which today correctly returns `08.04.2114`.

The problem is that I have to run this code on PHP 5.2 server, where this returns `01.01.1970`!!! **Would you know why and how can I fix this?**

EDIT: Based on the discussion under @D. Kasipovic's answer I found out that **the PHP 5.4 machine is 64 bit while the PHP 5.2 machine is 32 bit!!! So this would be the real reason, not the PHP version I guess!**

---

PS: Note that I am not sure if this is caused by PHP version, it could also be caused by the system limitation on the timestamp data type, as noted in the [documentation of strtotime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

> The valid range of a timestamp is typically from Fri, 13 Dec 1901 20:45:54 UTC to Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 UTC... Additionally, not all platforms support negative timestamps,
>   ... will not work on Windows, some Linux distributions ... 
>   For 64-bit versions of PHP, the valid range of a timestamp is effectively infinite, as 64 bits can represent approximately 293
>   billion years in either direction.

**Note that if I change `+100 years` to just `+10 years` it works perfectly on both systems!**

Comment: As far as I'm aware only a limited number of strtotime() options will work prior to PHP 5.3, so your limited as to what you can use for the 'now' parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use **+100 year** instead of **+100 years**,

**PHP 5.2.17**

```
<?php
    $date = new DateTime();
    $date->modify('+100 year');
    echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
?>
```

Check this <kbd>**[Demo Code Viper](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ZJe3HV)**</kbd>

Also check version of **PHP 5.2.17** its work perfect.

**PHP 5.4.9**

```
<?php
    $date = new DateTime();
    $date->modify('+100 years');  // $date->modify('+100 year');
    echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
?>
```

Check this <kbd>**[Demo Code Viper](http://codepad.viper-7.com/wSLedT)**</kbd>

Hope this would be help you!

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks! Note that mere change of "years" to "year" in the `strtotime` call didn't help.

Comment: BTW, would you know where the problem was? Was the problem in the version of PHP, or in the difference of the UNIX timestamp data type between the systems? "+10 years" works on both systems (please see my updated question)

Comment: So the difference between the machines was that the PHP 5.2 machine is only 32 bit, so this was almost surely the source of my problem, see my updated Q. It is interesting that the `DateTime` object doesn't have this limitation even on the 32 bit machine.

Answer (score 2):

There is a separate section mentioned about this on PHP Manual about `strtotime()`

> Note: Using this function for mathematical operations is not
>   advisable. It is better to use DateTime::add() and DateTime::sub() in
>   PHP 5.3 and later, or DateTime::modify() in PHP 5.2.

Check the notes section [**here**](https://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php#refsect1-function.strtotime-notes) , So it is advised to use `DateTime::modify()`

#### Remodify your code to... PHP 5.2 ready

```
<?php
$dt = new DateTime();
$dt->modify('+100 years');
echo $dt->format('d.m.Y');  //"prints" 08.04.2114
```

Comment: +1 thanks. 
BTW, would you know where the problem was? Was the problem in the version of PHP, or in the difference of the UNIX timestamp data type between the systems? "+10 years" works on both systems (please see my updated question).

Comment: @TMS, This is definitely has to do with PHP versions I think , Proof see [**here**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/TyYhE9) , the same code of yours works on PHP 5.2 ., So I assume that it is a 64 bit and the reason that it works.

Comment: Your comment is little confused, "This definitiely has to do with PHP versions" is false, as you yourself conclude - it has nothing to do with PHP version but the 64 vs 32 bit :-)

Comment: Hmm I meant the 64bit / 32Bit Versions of PC.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the description at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php it says the following:

> The valid range of a timestamp is typically from Fri, 13 Dec 1901
>   20:45:54 GMT to Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 GMT. (These are the dates
>   that correspond to the minimum and maximum values for a 32-bit signed
>   integer). However, before PHP 5.1.0 this range was limited from
>   01-01-1970 to 19-01-2038 on some systems (e.g. Windows).

I suppose this is your error.

Comment: Which one is it then? The year/years?

Comment: You need to use the `modify` of the `DateTime` class as an alternative , the reason behind that I have put on my answer from the manual link.

Comment: I believe the question is why it works on 5.4 but not on 5.2. I think that the OP is perfectly aware of other solutions, and just wants to know why it works on one and not on another.

Comment: Yes, this could be my error, it doesn't have to be caused by PHP version but also the limitation on the timestamp data type!

Comment: Yeah maybe the difference is between 32bit and 64bit systems?

Comment: @D.Kasipovic very likely! How can I know if my system is 32/64 bit? I don't see it in `phpinfo()`. I have shell console only on one of those systems, the other is shared hosting so I can launch only PHP code.

Comment: Try with `var_dump(PHP_INT_SIZE, PHP_INT_MAX)`. PHP_INT_SIZE of 8 means 64bit and 4 means 32bit.

Comment: Great thanks, you are correct! The difference is in the 32 vs 64 bit architecture!